# Obtener datos de facebook con ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, ionic2, facebook-api

estoy haciendo login con facebook con cordova-plugin-facebook4, lo inplemente como sale en la pagina principal https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/. Solo me da el id de facebook, quisiera traer el correo y el nombre.

Lo hice de esta manera

config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^1.9.1">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="APP_id" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="miproyecto" />
</plugin>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Pages } from '../pages/pages';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  pages
  .....
],
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,config, ['ngAnimate'])
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
 ......
],
providers: [
Notifying,
 {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
 ....
 Facebook
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

login.ts

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';


 export class Login {
   constructor(
    private fb: Facebook
   ) {}

   loginFace(ev?: Event){
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
     .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res)

        let idFacebook = res.authResponse.userID;

        this.fb.api(res.authResponse.userID+"/?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name", [])
          .then(re => console.log(res))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
     })
     .catch(e => {
       console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e)
     });
   }
 }
```

consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo, donde dice `.then(re => console.log(res))` debe decir `.then(re => console.log(re))` sin la `s`.. sino estas imprimiendo el resultado del otro request. salu2

Comment: @EmanuelVe Hola, muchas gracias no vi ese error, por favor ingreselo como respuesta para calificarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En dónde dice

```
  .then(re => console.log(res))
```

Remplazalo por

```
  .then(re => console.log(re))
```

Estás viendo el resultado de la primera solicitud.

Comment: Disculpa lo breve de la respuesta estoy con el celular XD

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido de la api de facebook que al obtener un login sólo te devolverá una llave de acceso y que con ella es que obtienes un json de autorización a los campos que requieres, eso si previamente tu app solicitó esos campos en la solicitud de logueo a facebook y la solucitud es a 
http://graph.facebook.com/{userId}?fields=id,email,name&access_token={access-token}